# Multiple selection(Shapes) in VBA, Tip needed

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 shapes(shp & shp1) with same property.I just wanted to know if there is a way to select both shapes(shp.select and shp1.select) so that i would not have to select twice and assign property twice.I tried worksheet.selectall but it results in error.I am just starter in these matter so i wanted to find a way to do it.

```
Private Sub RUN()
    Dim x As Long, cel As Range, ws As Worksheet, shp As Shape, y As Long, z As Long, orow As Long, ocol As Long, cel0 As Range, shp1 As Shape
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    orow = 3
    ocol = 3
    y = ws.Range("A4").Value
    z = ws.Range("A5").Value
'number shapes
    Set cel = Range("E6")
    Set cel0 = cel.Offset(orow * (z - 1) + 4, 0)
    For x = 1 To y
        Set shp = ws.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, cel.Left, cel.Top, cel.Width, cel.Width)
        Set shp1 = ws.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, cel0.Left, cel0.Top, cel0.Width, cel0.Width)
        shp.Select
         With Selection.ShapeRange
            .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
            With .TextFrame
             .Characters.Text = x
                .Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 3
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
                .VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
            End With
            With .Line
                .Visible = msoTrue
                .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                .Transparency = 0
            End With
        End With
        shp1.Select
        With Selection.ShapeRange
            .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
            With .TextFrame
             .Characters.Text = x
                .Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 3
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
                .VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
            End With
            With .Line
                .Visible = msoTrue
                .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                .Transparency = 0
            End With
        End With
        Set cel = cel.Offset(0, ocol)
        Set cel0 = cel0.Offset(0, ocol)
        Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ws.Shapes.SelectAll` in order to select all shapes on the sheet.

In order to select two specific shapes, you can use the next way:

```
 Dim sel As ShapeRange
  Set sel = ws.Shapes.Range(Array(ws.Shapes(1).Name, ws.Shapes(2).Name))
  sel.Select
```

In order to use your specific way (shp & shp1), you must name them after creation. `shp.Name = "xx"` and `shp1.Name = "yy"` and then use that in the next way:

```
 Dim sel As ShapeRange
  Set sel = ws.Shapes.Range(Array("xx", "yy"))
   'or
  Set sel = ws.Shapes.Range(Array(shp.Name, shp1.Name))
   sel.Select
   'but they must have different names, in order to be individually identified!
```

Now, please use the next (your) adapted code able to do what (I understood) you need. It is commented in the relevant areas and I think it is easy to be uderstood. Do not forget to have a value in cell "A4"... The code firstly delete the existing shapes, if any. If you do not need that, you can comment those lines:

```
Private Sub RUN()
    Dim x As Long, cel As Range, ws As Worksheet, shp As Shape, y As Long, z As Long
    Dim orow As Long, ocol As Long, cel0 As Range, shp1 As Shape
    Dim sel As ShapeRange, sh As Shape 'new declarations

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    orow = 3: ocol = 3

    y = ws.Range("A4").value
    z = ws.Range("A5").value

    Set cel = Range("E6")
    Set cel0 = cel.Offset(orow * (z - 1) + 4, 0)

    'New: delete all existingn shapes, if any_______________
      ws.Shapes.SelectAll: Selection.Delete
    '_______________________________________________________

    'firstly create all shapes and write their TextFrame text:
    For x = 1 To y
        Set shp = ws.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, cel.left, cel.top, cel.width, cel.width)
          shp.TextFrame.Characters.text = x
        Set shp1 = ws.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, cel0.left, cel0.top, cel0.width, cel0.width)
          shp1.TextFrame.Characters.text = x

        Set cel = cel.Offset(0, ocol)
        Set cel0 = cel0.Offset(0, ocol)
    Next x
     'create the shaperange of all existing shapes___
     ws.Shapes.SelectAll
     Set sel = Selection.ShapeRange
     '_______________________________________________
    'Changge what can be done at once (except TextFrame properties)
    With sel
        .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
        With .Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            .Transparency = 0
        End With
    End With
    '____________________________________________________________

    'Change TextFrame properties (individually for each shape):
    For Each sh In sel
        With sh.TextFrame
            .Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 3
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
        End With
    Next
    '__________________________________________________________
End Sub
```

Comment: It shows:"Application-defined or Object-Defined Error"

Comment: Do you have any shape on `ws` sheet?

Comment: Is there a way to select like- shp & shp1.select

Comment: Yes, but not in this way. I will edit my answer with the way you need...

Comment: No shapes on sheet.

Comment: @Pramod Pandit: So, what to be selected if no any shape on the sheet...? The code is able to select all (existing) shapes...

Comment: shp and shp1 creates the shape.Initially there are no shapes on sheet.

Comment: @Pramod Pandit: So, you must select the existing shapes ONLY AFTER THEIR CREATION, please. In your code, I mean. Otherwise, there is nothing to be selected. I also edited my answer and presented other ways to specifically select two shapes according to their names.

Comment: "Set sel = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(ActiveSheet.shp.Name, ActiveSheet.shp1.Name))"--Object does not support this property or method

Comment: @Pramod Pandit: Did you use `Dim sel As ShapeRange`? Did you differently name your `shp` and `shp1`?

Comment: Private Sub RUN()
    Dim x As Long, cel As Range, ws As Worksheet, shp As Shape, y As Long, z As Long, orow As Long, ocol As Long, cel0 As Range, shp1 As Shape, sel As ShapeRange
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set sel = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(ActiveSheet.Shapes(shp).Name, ActiveSheet.Shapes(shp1).Name))

Comment: @Pramod Pandit: I do not need your all code. I simple asked: Did you use `Dim sel As ShapeRange`? Did you differently name your `shp` and `shp1`? Can you answer this question, please? I do not see the answer at my questions. And you must use the code I supplied **after you create your shapes and name them as I recommended**...

Comment: Sorry,I used Dim sel as shaperange and i did not differently name shp and shp1.

Comment: `"shp.Name = "xx" shp1.Name = "yy" 
 Dim sel As ShapeRange
  Set sel = ws.Shapes.Range(Array("xx", "yy"))"`-->It returns object variable or with block variable not set.

Comment: @Pramod Pandit: This is not possible! Did you use this lines AFTER YOU CREATED THE SHAPES? Can you edit your question and post the new adapted code? But below the existing one... Write, please: Edited: The updated code:

Comment: Sorry for making you frustated.I know i need to work on my VBA skills but the things you told me is little over my head.I've posted my complete code.Can you help me with it ?

Comment: @Pramod Pandit: This is not so complicated like it looks... So, I could see you edited your question but you did not post the modified code. What should I check in order to suggest you something to be corrected? I do not know how you used my suggestions. I have a different proposition: Try manually creating of some shapes, then run my three code samples on that sheet. Does it select your shapes? If yes, you must start understanding the code and do what I suggest...

Comment: @Pramod Pandit: Since you look overwhelmed by the way of using my ideas, I will adapt your code in order to work for as many (pair of shapes) you need... Please, test it and let me know if it works as you need.

Comment: Before implementing your ideas I was learning about arrays on youtube.I used your code & it worked smoothly as expected.Thank you for that.I will further dive into your code to learn.THANK YOU !!

Answer (score 1):

### Looping Through the Shapes Collection

```
Option Explicit

' Write Shapes Names to the Immediate window (CTRL+G)
Sub ShapesNames()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim shp As Shape

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    For Each shp In ws.Shapes
        Debug.Print shp.Name
    Next shp

End Sub

' Now add the names you wish to an array (vntSh).
Sub ShapesChangeProperties()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim vntSh As Variant

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    vntSh = Array(ws.Shapes("Oval 10"), ws.Shapes("Oval 16"))

    ' Use For Each to loop through the shapes.
    Dim vnt As Variant
    For Each vnt In vntSh
        Debug.Print vnt.Name
    Next vnt

    ' or:

    ' Use For Next to loop through the shapes.
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(vntSh)
        Debug.Print vntSh(i).Name
    Next i

End Sub
```

**Applied to your code**

```
Sub ForEach()

    Dim vntSh As Variant
    Dim vnt As Variant
    vntSh = Array(shp, shp1)

    For Each vnt In vntSh
        With vnt
            .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
            With .TextFrame
                .Characters.Text = x
                .Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 3
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
                .VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
            End With
            With .Line
                .Visible = msoTrue
                .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                .Transparency = 0
            End With
        End With
    Next vnt

End Sub

' or:

Sub ForNext()

    Dim vntSh As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    vntSh = Array(shp, shp1)

    For i = 0 To UBound(vntSh)
        With vntSh(i)
            .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
            With .TextFrame
                .Characters.Text = x
                .Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 3
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
                .VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
            End With
            With .Line
                .Visible = msoTrue
                .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                .Transparency = 0
            End With
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```